# my site gives me "connection timed out" after some page requests

Tags: out, timed

I have built a little browser game all in html, js and php where you have your character and the more you win the more you gain points and bla bla bla.... In this game ther's a problem: there are a lot of page redirects and this couse a "connection timed out" after clicking for a while (like 50-100 pages?..). I dont know any method to program my game without redirect.. should i use flash?... never done before... really dont know.

Anyway, could this problem been caused by some ridondance of code ... or whatelse... or it can be a limitation of my (free)domain host? (hostinghood.com)

i know that probably this is spam but if you want to try yourself type "vangers hostinghood" on google.. a registration is needed.. if you think that is phishing dont do it, but i promise that is secure. I dont want problems.

so.. How can i solve this issue?

(eventually, sorry for my english.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  A good SO question will have an easily reproducible case and usually includes the steps you have taken to solve your problem so far.

Comment: Separately, it's pretty concerning that you have so many redirects.  You say you don't know an alternate technique- what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, there are "fight" & "add points" functions. "Fight" matches you versus a random player, you attack it and you go to "won" or "lost" page.
"add points" add 1 point to the character stat you chose if you have at least 1.
So, for every action you will spend like 2-3 seconds, and this actions are ripetitive.
In the first case we have: fight.php-->win/loose.php-->fightagain/rest. If you fight again the cicle restart. So you can switch 100 pages in few minutes. In the second case, if you have e.g. 50 points to distribute, you will refresh the page and send querys to db 50 times in few seconds.

Comment: Any answear?... Up..